# Photoshop: how to replicate this text effect?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, photoshop-effects

I need to put these words into another image for a wallpaper with the exact same effect/look. I tried selecting it but the quality is low and the texts look bad.

[image]

Comment: Text and some mask, clipping layer, text effects... there's many different simple ways to do it. What have you tried?

Comment: nothing i have only started learning . i just tried cutting it or selecting it and it didnt produce what i wanted . I wanted to know how to produce the effect that the bold text has

Comment: If you want to know more about the site, please see [help]. Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 20):

That just looks like some type with a texture overlay.

1. Write some text...

   [image]
2. Find an appropriate texture<sup>[1]</sup>...

   [image]
3. Clip the texture to the type. You can either do that through the menu (*Layer → Create Clipping Mask*), or just <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>click</kbd> between the texture and type layers...

   [image]
4. You can use a layer style on the texture itself to adjust the colors (or use any method you'd otherwise use to recolor an image)...

   [image]

---

<sup>[1] Watercolor texture from [Freepik](http://www.freepik.com/free-vector/watercolor-background-in-abstract-style_939892.htm)</sup>

Comment: Excuse the typo...

Comment: but i want the exact same effects and same colors as the picture mentioned above . anyways thanks

Comment: Then find the same font, the same texture and recreate it as I explained...

Answer (score 0):

You would need to have two fonts, set both fonts up in the way shown above then select each of the thicker text layers.

After doing so you should get your either same background or different coloured backgrounds.

Now, select the text layer go onto the background layer. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>, this should select the background leaving you with text with a background fill. If you cannot find a background, or dont want to follow this you dont have too as you can always synthetically create this effect, but I personally wouldnt as my method is much easier and takes much less time.

But if you wanted to create that *EXACT* effect I would add transparent smoke effect (or create your own) over the top within the same effect.

Just to warn you if you are following my method and are going to use the composition commercially then you will have to check which images you use as some of these images could be copyrighted.

---

Comment: you need to be more detailed please. does your method mean i can take the texts out from this image and put it in another or create new texts?

Comment: @user91844 its the same as method just slightly different

Comment: and what do you mean by  using transparent smokes effect?

Comment: search up on google "transparent smoke effect" click on an image that has **NO** background and then add that under the mask of the other image @user91844

Answer (score 0):

Method 1:

One way to achieve this kind of effect is by using Layer Style. This might not give you the same the colours but it can give similar kind of effect.

You can download any Watercolor Layer Style. Once downloaded double click on it and the style will be added in the Layer Style Palette.

Open a new document and write your text. Select the text layer you want to apply the effect on. And then from the downloaded styles select any Layer Style. The style will be applied to the text.

[image]

Method 2:

Download some brushes. For example http://qbrushes.net/downloads/images/set-preview/water-color-photoshop-brushes-view.jpg

Open a New Document. Write your text. Select the color that is used in the images by using eye dropper tool.

Create a new layer above the text layer. Select the text by clicking on thumbnail.

Keeping the text selected, now select the new layer created above the text layer.

Apply the brushes on the layer by selecting different colors with eye dropper tool. 
[image]

[image]

Comment: i want the same effects and the colors as the picture mentioned above

Comment: Then in that case you will have to search styles with exact colors.  Or else you will have to create it manually by using brushes and different kind of effects. @user91844

Comment: yes .i was looking for response that will teach me how to duplicate that. anyway will try yours and see what it will produce thanks

Comment: I have edited my answer and shown how you can do it manually. @user91844

Comment: @user91844 there is no response that will teach you to search the web and find the exact font you need or the exact texture you need. *you* need to put in effort. We explained the tools, now you got to learn how to work with them.

Comment: YES this was all what i needed. Thanks very much .

Comment: If my answer helped you, request your to approve/upvote it. Thanks :) @user91844

Answer (score -2):

This is another way to achieve this goal.

1. Make your **Gradient**, first by Gradient tool.

[image: photoshop-how-to-replicate-this-text-effect]

2. Selection your text by Ctrl+Click on **text layer**

[image: photoshop-how-to-replicate-this-text-effect]

3. Create a **New Layer** and Apply the **Gradient Color** that you made a little bit ago.

[image: photoshop-how-to-replicate-this-text-effect]

4. Now delete the selections, Because, we don't need here any **Gradient Color**

[image: photoshop-how-to-replicate-this-text-effect]

5. Final Result

[image: photoshop-how-to-replicate-this-text-effect]

Comment: Selections to do this are really not the way you should be teaching someone. Masks and layer styles are the safer option and leave room for altering text etc.